# Detecting geometrical shapes in a handwritten flow chart

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How can I detect and segment shapes in a flow chart as shown  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf1te8908ss7okw/c%20%286%29.jpg?dl=0) using opencv?.

I want to detect each shape including lines like in [this](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/projects/udsi/noto-thesis.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestions:
As you have only squared forms you can use hough lines probabilistic from opencv. With it you will obtain all small segments from flow chart. Try to connect the lines found forming the charts elements.

Comment: Thanxs David, I already done this using Hough lines but they miss some shapes some time and i have to implement this very accurate so can't just rely on Hough Lines.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting shapes - OK.

Reading computer generated flow charts - possible with some research effort,

Drawn by hand - not OK,

Handwritten flowcharts - no way.

Even today's OCR tech is not %100 for images having handwritten texts at unknown, random locations.

I would start with ideal shapes (without rotations etc.), find a base algorithm and generalize for computer written charts - like lucidchart drawn ones. Then find a way out for hand written ones working on a hand written image set, each having different obstacles on problems like *unconnected lines, rotations, rounded vs perpendicular corners, untied shapes*...

I believe, if you somehow manage to do that - *after receiving ICCV & CVPR awards*, you will have lots of assumptions for it to work, so someone can still draw just another chart that bugs out the algorithm.

Comment: i just have to detect shapes only not text and yes you are write ,i am facing a lot of issues regarding rotation,unconnected lines ...etc ,i tried squares.cpp given in opencv samples as well but issue remains as it is.

Comment: I want to implement [this](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/projects/udsi/noto-thesis.pdf)  paper basically

Comment: nice! as you can see even a great thesis study cannot cover all the possibilities, with lots of future works and to dos; but it is a good starting point!